# Which circuit simulator can be used with ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm seeking for a circuit simulator for Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Qucs is what's recommended in the UbuntuEngineering wiki:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuEngineering

It's stated to be available in the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Qucs is not available in the repositories, it was last available in Precise.  It looks like the project is also unmaintained as well.  (Many of those help pages are outdated)

Comment: If someone is interested, I managed to create a snap with the last QUCS available in 16.04 via PPA. Works quite well, I think.

Comment: Qucs is still under (slow) development. http://qucs.sourceforge.net/install.html#install_ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

Based on experience on using a few, here are my recommendations based on the [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuEngineering) @P05TMAN suggested and can be easily found on the Ubuntu Software Store.

- [Icarus Verilog](http://icarus.com/eda/verilog/)
- [Eagle](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/overview)

Although these are more on the intermediate/advanced level, they allow you to do more complex operations and design but requires some background and knowledge of the software/language.

Comment: Eagle is a circuit design software, not a simulator. Same goes for Fritzing.

Comment: https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/spice-simulation-part-1/

Comment: Aah, I suppose it's new.

Comment: Yup and thanks for bringing up fritzing as well, I went ahead and edited my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `apt search circuit`, we can get a list of available packages that contains the word "circuit" somewhere in their description. I picked a few (11) candidates of that list which seemed most relevant to me and copied their descriptions from `apt show PACKAGENAME` here:

```
cl-rlc/xenial,xenial 0.1.3-3 all
  Common Lisp RLC Circuit Simulator

Description: Common Lisp RLC Circuit Simulator
 cl-rlc provides a simulator for RLC (resistance, inductance, capacitance)
 circuits. It is written in Common Lisp and uses the xgraph package for
 plotting.


eagle/xenial 6.6.0-2 i386
  Printed circuit board design tool

Description: Printed circuit board design tool
 Eagle includes a layout editor, schematic editor, and an autorouter. The
 following limitations apply to the EAGLE Light Edition: The usable board
 area is limited to 100 x 80 mm (4 x 3.2 inches). Only two signal layers
 can be used (Top and Bottom). The schematic editor can only create one
 sheet.
 .
 Use of eagle freeware is limited to non-profit or evaluation purposes. See
 /usr/share/doc/eagle/copyright for more information.


electric/xenial,xenial 9.06+dfsg-1 all
  electrical CAD system

Description: electrical CAD system
 Electric is a sophisticated electrical CAD system that can handle many
 forms of circuit design, including custom IC layout (ASICs), schematic
 drawing, hardware description language specifications, and electro-
 mechanical hybrid layout.


fritzing/xenial 0.9.2b+dfsg-3 amd64
  Easy-to-use electronic design software

Description: Easy-to-use electronic design software
 Fritzing is an open source project designed to help one transition from a
 prototype to a finished project. Aimed at users who want to produce or
 document circuits and experiments, one starts by building a physical
 prototype, then recreating it with Fritzing’s graphical editor. From there
 one can generate a schematic, PCB artwork, and PCB production files.


geda/xenial,xenial 1:1.8.2-5 all
  GPL EDA -- Electronics design software (metapackage)

Description: GPL EDA -- Electronics design software (metapackage)
 The gEDA project has produced and continues working on a full GPL'd suite
 and toolkit of Electronic Design Automation tools. These tools are used
 for electrical circuit design, schematic capture, simulation, prototyping,
 and production. Currently, the gEDA project offers a mature suite of free
 software applications for electronics design, including schematic capture,
 attribute management, bill of materials (BOM) generation, netlisting into
 over 20 netlist formats, analog and digital simulation, and printed
 circuit board (PCB) layout.
 .
 This is a metapackage which depends on the components required for a
 typical gEDA installation.


gnucap/xenial 1:0.36~20091207-2 amd64
  GNU Circuit Analysis package

Description: GNU Circuit Analysis package
 GNUCAP is a general purpose circuit simulator.  It performs nonlinear dc
 and transient analyses, Fourier analysis, and ac analysis linearized at an
 operating point.  It is fully interactive and command driven.  It can also
 be run in batch mode or as a server. The output is produced as it
 simulates.  Spice compatible models for the MOSFET (level 1,2,3) and diode
 are included in this release.


gspiceui/xenial 1.1.00+dfsg-1build1 amd64
  Graphical user interface for gnucap and ngspice

Description: Graphical user interface for gnucap and ngspice
 Gspiceui is a graphichal user interface for the two freely available electronic 
 circuit engines: GNU-Cap and Ng-Spice. Current features are:
  * Import gschem schematic files using gentlist.
  * Load and parse circuit description (net list) files.
  * Provides a GUI interface for GNU-Cap OP, DC, AC and Transient analyses and
  generates appropriate simulator commands based on user input.
  * Provides a GUI interface for Ng-Spice DC, AC and Transient analyses and
  generates appropriate simulator commands based on user input.
  * The raw output may be viewed for any processes initiated by gspiceui.


kicad/xenial 4.0.2+dfsg1-4 amd64
  Electronic schematic and PCB design software

Description: Electronic schematic and PCB design software
 Kicad is a suite of programs for the creation of printed circuit boards.
 It includes a schematic editor, a PCB layout tool, support tools and a 3D
 viewer to display a finished & fully populated PCB.
 .
 Kicad is made up of 5 main components:
 .
  * kicad - project manager
  * eeschema - schematic editor
  * pcbnew - PCB editor
  * gerbview - GERBER viewer
  * cvpcb - footprint selector for components
 .
 Libraries:
  * Both eeschema and pcbnew have library managers and editors for their
    components and footprints
  * You can easily create, edit, delete and exchange library items
  * Documentation files can be associated with components, footprints and key
    words, allowing a fast search by function
  * Very large libraries are available for schematic components and footprints
  * Most components have corresponding 3D models


ngspice/xenial 26-1build1 amd64
  Spice circuit simulator

Description: Spice circuit simulator
 NGspice is a mixed-level/mixed-signal circuit simulator. Its code is based
 on three open source software packages: Spice3f5, Cider1b1 and Xspice.
 .
 NGspice is part of gEDA project, a full GPL'd suite of Electronic Design
 Automation tools.


oregano/xenial 0.70-3ubuntu1 amd64
  tool for schematical capture of electronic circuits

Description: tool for schematical capture of electronic circuits
 Oregano is a GNOME application for schematic capture and printing of
 electronic circuits. It can simulate the circuits using Gnucap, ng-spice
 or Berkeley spice.


tkgate/xenial 2.0~b10-4ubuntu2 amd64
  Tcl/Tk based digital circuit editor and simulator

Description: Tcl/Tk based digital circuit editor and simulator
 TkGate is a digital circuit editor and simulator with a Tcl/Tk based
 interface. TkGate includes a large number of built-in devices including basic
 gates, memories, ttys and modules for hierarchical design. The simulator can
 be controlled either interactively or through a simulation script. Memory
 contents can be loaded from files, and a microcode/macrocode compiler (gmac)
 is included to create tkgate memory files from a high-level description. The
 simulator supports continuous simulation, single step simulation (by clock or
 epoch) and breakpoints. Save files are in a Verilog-like format.
 .
 TkGate also includes a number of tutorial and example circuits which can be
 loaded through the "Help" menu. The examples range from a simple gate-level
 3-bit adder to a 16-bit CPU programmed to play the "Animals" game.
 .
 TkGate has a multi-language interface with support for English, Japanese,
 French and Spanish.
```

Note: I didn't try any of these, just providing a list of candidates that looked promising to me.

Answer (score 1):

**EAGLE Free**
I [found](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/free-download) it today and tried it out. It works good so far. It runs from desktop in browser like app. I haven't tried to use it offline to see if it works without an internet connection like other similar apps I have on my Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: "From desktop in browser like app" ?

Comment: https://electronjs.org/

Comment: Okay? It doesn't run using electron. It just runs in a desktop app, using python-qt

Comment: Wait. Why are you here? The question was "I'm seeking for a circuit simulator for Ubuntu 16.04". electronjs.org offers a cross-platform framework ("browser like app"). This thread isn't about what framework and neither are your post. StackExchange is not for trolls. Get lost.

Comment: You said it "runs from desktop in browser-like app". Then you brought up electron. The answer should be "it runs from a desktop app". Calling it "browser-like" is not really accurate. And Electron is great btw, I use it regularly.